# Angularjs templateUrl couldn't find ngTemplate in ngInclude

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have trouble with templateUrl when it's have an ngTemplate in ngInclude.

My **index.html**

`<div ng-include="'./html/root.html'"></div>`

My **root.html**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">
<div class="content">
    <div class="group">
        <div ng-bind-html="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</script>
<div ng-view></div>
```

My **routeProvider.js**

```
$routeProvider.when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'home.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        })
```

This wasn't find home.html in ngTemplate. I think this couldn't find "home.html" because root.html has ng-view that in ngInclude.

Note 1: When I put my `<script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">`  in index.html it's working.

Note 2: When I change my **routeProvider.js** with;

```
$routeProvider.when('/home', {
            template: "<div ng-include=\"'home.html'\"></div>",
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        })
```

It's work too.

How can I fix that?

Comment: See your browser console\network log, there would be some 404 error which would give you an idea about what url is being hit.

Comment: My console look like this http://postimg.org/image/88rxzkge5/ . In (index):31 section refer this: angular.element(document).ready(function () {
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['CicekSepetiModule']);
        });

Answer (score 0):

Please note a few things at first.

When you are using templateUrl, angular expects an url to which the html content is residing.(This is basically for accessing a file with the html markup).

What you can do is, keep the content in some a file with the name as home.html and provide the link to the file inside the templateurl.

Or You have to provide the templateUrl with the url of the physical file which contains the template and then use template to fetch the template with the specific Id.